# use native postgres query request instead of using rest_framework viewset objects

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, reactjs, postgresql, django-rest-framework

so here is my problem i am using django rest_framework in backend with reactjs in the frontend and postgres as database and i am tired of trying to understand how works classes and objects in rest viewset i am actually in deadline in my project so i need to speed up i am using postgres since 2 years now and i am new to django rest and reactjs (3 mounth) so i know how to write and get evrything i want by postgres native request so the thing is that i want to a native postgres request to get something from the viewset
for exemple i want to write "SELECT * FROM table" instead of "Table.Objects.all()" BUT i want to use different postgres request depending on the request.query.params
here is some of my code so that u use it for ur reponse:

**models.py** (part of it)
'''

```
class Evennement(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    date_evennement = models.DateField()
    time_evennement = models.TimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'evennement'
```

'''

**serializer.py**
'''

```
class EvennementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    


    class Meta:
        model = Evennement

        fields = '__all__'
```

'''

**views.py**(part of it)
'''

```
class EvennementViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = Evennement.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EvennementSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        

        if request.query.consultation_evennement: //executing this query if the parameter in the get request is true
            //how can i change the queryset variable declared above i use "SELECT * FROM Evennement" instead

self.queryset =  //doenst work
queryset = //doesnt work


            return super().retrieve(request)

        return super().retrieve(request)
```

'''

thanks in advance for your answer :'(